# High performance R libraries for interactive graphics

Tags: r, visualization

In the past few years there has been an explosion in the quantity and quality of available data visualization tools in R. I've long ago stopped using `plot` base graphics in favor of the wonderful `ggplot2` package, and I'm considering going for interactivity now, perhaps using one of the JS-integration packages, and outputting HTML.

However, I'm often in the business of creating long HTML report pages with dozens of graphics in there, and I care about a number of factors:

- load-time for the graphics generated cannot be too long.
- should work decently with Shiny and Rmarkdown (ideally flexdashboard).
- should have a non-insane syntax for tweaking options (i.e no 20 line JS code inserts to change legend location).
- should be relatively well-documented.
- should be actively maintained.

**What are your go-to packages for interactive data viz?**

Comment: How many objects? How many frames/s?

Comment: dozens and dozens respectively.

Answer (score 2):

My current go-to are some graphics from Rstudio's `flexdashboard` and a set of relatively well-maintained packages:

> **[Leaflet](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/)**, a library for creating dynamic maps that support panning and
>   zooming, with various annotations like markers, polygons, and popups.
>
> **[dygraphs](http://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs)**, which provides rich facilities for charting time-series data
>   and includes support for many interactive features including
>   series/point highlighting, zooming, and panning.
>
> **[Plotly](https://plot.ly/r/)**, which via its ggplotly interface allows you to easily
>   translate your ggplot2 graphics to an interactive web-based version.
>
> **[rbokeh](http://hafen.github.io/rbokeh)**, an interface to Bokeh, a powerful declarative Bokeh framework
>   for creating web-based plots.
>
> **[Highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/)**, a rich R interface to the popular Highcharts JavaScript
>   graphics library.

Source: [Flexdashboard Components](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#components)